# Unable to prevent encrypted boot partition from being automatically mounted

Tags: mount, encryption, fstab, luks

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed with `/root`, `swap`, and `/home` as logical volumes inside a LUKS2 container and a separate `/boot` inside a LUKS1 container. I would like the `/boot` partition to not be automatically mounted on boot so it stays encrypted during normal operation. I've tried adding `noauto` to both `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab`, but I'm still asked for the `/boot` partition password at startup and `/boot` still gets mounted. I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/490231) which said that it might be because the EFI system partition is automatically mounted, so I added `noauto` to the ESP in `/etc/fstab` too. This prevented the ESP from being automatically mounted, but `/boot` still gets mounted. The only way I was able to prevent his was to remove the entry from `/etc/fstab` or `/etc/crypttab`, but I would like to keep the entry.

Here's `/etc/crypttab`:

```
cryptboot UUID=... none luks,discard,noauto
cryptdrive UUID=... none luks,discard
```

And `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root / ext4 erros=remount-ro 0 1
/dev/mapper/cryptboot /boot ext4 noauto 0 2
UUID=5E3C-E672 /boot/efi vfat umask=0077,noauto 0 1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-home /home ext4 defaults 0 2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap none swap sw 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that `/boot` was being mounted because the `unattended-upgrades.service` systemd unit was enabled and it depended on `boot.mount`. I figured this out by running `systemctl list-dependencies boot.mount --all --reverse`. Disabling `unattended-upgrades.service` worked.